# Scrape page open in new tab using puppeter

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a list of item on page now on click on each item new tab is opened, which I need to parse and get back to original page and then click the next item. So this need to be done repeatedly for all item. The code is mentioned below:

```js
for(let k =0 ;k<item_arr.length;k++) {

    let item_id = item_arr[k];
    console.log("=====inside for loop======");
    console.log("=====ITEM ID:::::======"+item_id);

    try
    {
        console.log("=====before click======");

        let item_d = await page.$('div[id="'+item_id+'"]');
        await item_d.click();
        console.log("=====after click======");

    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log("Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> :"+e);
    }

    pages = await browser.pages();
    count = pages.length;
    console.log("==========count number of pages"+count);

}
```

I am getting error as mentioned below:

```
(node:12280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: pages is not defined
```

So how to handle the scraping?

Comment: It seems the error means you do not declare `pages` variable. Try `const pages = await browser.pages();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think pages is an object and not an array so needs to be addressed as,

```
Object.keys(pages).length
```

I load pages/tabs like this, which might not be of use.

```
const pages = await browser.pages();
await pages[0].setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 1080 })
await pages[0].goto(URL);
```